# Sample Sample is not a valid value for NCName

Tags: app-store, xsd, titanium, google-play, titanium-mobile

My appname () was "Sample Sample" which was working fine till Ti-SDK 2.1.3,
After i updated to Ti SDK 3.0.0 and MVC alloy it is showing "Sample Sample is not a valid value for NCName" and generates a red-x pop-up error message in the TiApp Editor in Tiapp.xml.
This is very critical for me as previous version is on appstore and need to update the same quickly. 
Thanx

Comment: sample? code snippet? something would help get this answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String internationalization helps to avoid this problem
http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/02/internationalization-of-app-names.html#appxml

Answer (score 0):

It relates to this bug:

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-12171?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

Having spaces in the  node of tiapp.xml triggers the issue:
`<name>App Test</name>`